# Features combinations

Tags: weka

I have a list of features set (40 features) and my idea firstly was to evaluate the classifier on all the combinations that I can get. However, after I did some calculations I found that the combinations will reach millions!! Thus, it will take forever!!!!

I read about the ability of using random search method to chose random features. However, each time I run the random search I got the same features sets. Do I need to change the seed number or any option??

Also, Is using random search effective and can substitute the approach of choosing all combinations???

I would appreciate your help experts.

Many thanks in advance,

Ahmad

Answer (score 4):

When you want to perform an attribute selection in WEKA, yo should take into account 2 algorithms, the searcher and the attribute evaluator (I will talk about it later).

As you said, maybe you cannot try an `Exhaustive search` because it takes so long, there are greedy alternatives to get good results (depending on the problem) like `Best first` (based on `hill climbing`). The option that you comment (`Random search`) is another approach to make the selection subsets, it makes random iterations to select subsets that will be evaluated.

Why are you getting the same subset of selected attributes? Because the `Random search` is selecting always the same subsets and the evaluator determines the best one (final output). But if I change the `seed` parameter it should change. Maybe or... maybe not. Why? Because if the algorithm performs an enough number of iterations (although it starts with a different seed) it will get the same subsets than the previous one (convergence) and the evaluator will choose the same subset as the previous execution.

If you do not want to get convergence in the selector output, just change the `seed`, but choose a smaller `search percent` to limit the exploration and get different results.

But, in my opinion, if you are getting always the same results is because the evaluator (I do not know what algorithm are you using) has determined that this subset is "the best" given your dataset. I also recommend you to try another selector like `Best first` or a `Genetic search` as your search method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arutaku. Do appreciate it. The thing is that my idea was to test all different combinations for the 40 features and identify best combination result with cost sensitive classifiers. If I apply Best First or Genetic search the resulted features will not list the most possible combinations. Bottom line, whhat do you recommend to apply in order to list most combinations of the features?? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The evaluator will provide best result depending on the provided dataset. The thing is i need to maintain most features combinations (even though it may provide very low accuracy results)

Comment: If you want to test "all different combinations" just try `Exhaustive search`. But if you want the results sorted in descending order, that is not search method stuff, it depends on the `evaluator`. If you want to get a statistical idea of which attributes are better just try `Ranker` as search method and `Principal Components` as evaluator, it gives you correlations and eigenvectors for each attribute.